# Practice fieldset with checkbox

Tags: html

I am starting to learn HTML and I am trying to do an exercise that I must use two fieldset and here is the code:

```
<title>Practice Page</title>
```

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Profile</legend>
    Name:<input type="text"><br/>
    Email:<input type="text><br/
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Themes</legend>
    <input type="checkbox">HTML
    <input type="checkbox">CSS
</fieldset>
```

When I open it in a browser the following appears:

[Practice fieldset with checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CYLU.png)

I have to create another fieldset with the name "theme" but it takes me to mean that I am only doing one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing quotes (") of the second `input`.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Profile</legend>
    Name:<input type="text"><br/>
    Email:<input type="text><br/
<!--                       ▲
                           │
                         here
-->
</fieldset>
```

Your example works like the following:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Profile</legend>
    Name:<input type="text"><br/>
    Email:<input type="text"><br/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Themes</legend>
    <input type="checkbox">HTML
    <input type="checkbox">CSS
</fieldset>
```

Note that the syntax highlighting already tells you that. You can see that the  in the lower part is not colored as the top part. That should already raise your attention.

Comment: Thanks you, it's work. I dont see the colored because i'm nos using a program. I'm using notepad of windows.

Comment: Ah, then you should immediately change that! **ALWAYS** use a proper [IDE](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)! There are tons of  advantages, e.g. code highlighting (which makes coding more readable), debugging tools, tooltips about functions ect., auto completion, ...

Answer (score 0):

Email:<input type="text><br/

you are missing double quotes and closing tag on br